# how to display pdf file in pop u window in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

i a m already done my pdf view but now i want just view dynamically pdf file pop window not download option and save option so please give some example in java
i a m use this code now

```
File f= new File(file);
if(f.exists()){
ServletOutputStream op= response.getOutputStream();
response.reset();
if(check==1){
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
}else{
response.setContentType(content);
                    }
// response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;      filename=" +fileName);
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
int length;
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(buf)) != -1)){
op.write(buf,0,length);
            }
in.close();
op.flush();
op.close();
    }
```

Comment: i answered it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591425/add-pdf-and-tiff-to-the-same-pdf-document-and-display-it-in-the-browser?noredirect=1#comment29331909_19591425

Comment: i answered it here. My pdf opens in  different window.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591425/add-pdf-and-tiff-to-the-same-pdf-document-and-display-it-in-the-browser?noredirect=1#comment29331909_19591425

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without using external libraries like iText.

The ability to download or save the pdf from browser is a property present in the PDF , which the pdf plugin in the browser reads and enable that in the browser. So you have to disable that property in the PDF itself in order for the browser to enforce that constraint.

Here is an example link
http://www.coderanch.com/t/329511/java/java/revoke-permission-save-copy-PDF