# Add pdf and tiff to the same pdf document and display it in the browser

Tags: java, jsp, ftp, itext, apache-commons

I am using the below code to retrieve a file from an ftp server and display it in the browser.

```
boolean fileFormatType = fileName.endsWith(".PDF");
     if (fileFormatType) {
        if (FilePdf != null && FilePdf.length() > 0) {
             is = ftp.retrieveFileStream(strFile);
             bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
             response.reset();
             response.setContentType("application/pdf");
             response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                  "inline;filename=example.pdf");
             ServletOutputStream outputStream = response
                      .getOutputStream();
             System.out.println("here ");
             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
             int readCount;

             while ((readCount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0){
                 outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
             }
             outputStream.flush();
             outputStream.close();
         }
       } else {
             is = ftp.retrieveFileStream(strFile);
             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = convertTIFFtoPDF(is);
             response.setContentType("application/pdf");
             response.setContentLength(baos.size());
             response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                    "attachment;filename=\"" + "importDocs.pdf" + "\"");
             ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
             baos.writeTo(out);
             out.flush();
             out.close();
```

But now, i need to add the multiple files in a folder (the folder could contain PDFs and TIFFs) and display them all at a time in a browser. I have been trying unsuccessfully for the past three days. I could post the code that i tried here but i want a fresh opinion/approach. Please help me solve this. I am using itextpdf5.1 commons-io.util apis

I get a negative array size exception btw.

Comment: Please update your question with the answers to these questions: how does this question relate to iText? What is the stack trace? What do you mean by negative array size exception? (Is it an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?) Can you reproduce the problem in a standalone application (not a servlet).

Comment: Mr Lowagie. I couldnt realise where the problem was so i had to also mention that im using Itext. But i was able to solve this. I will post the solution. thanks for being active on this forum.

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer. I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final answer to my problem.

```
for (PdfBean pdfBean : list)
            {
                if(!pdfBean.getFileName().isEmpty()&&!pdfBean.getFileLocation().isEmpty()){


                msgDH.InsertUserHistDtls(pdfBean.getHawb(), userId, pdfBean.getCustomer(), pdfBean.getFileName(), pdfBean.getProduct(), pdfBean.getDocType(), "Print");
                msgDH.InsertLogDtls(pdfBean.getFileName(), pdfBean.getProduct(), pdfBean.getCustomer(), userId);

                FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
                int tiffPages = 0;
                try
                {
                    ftp.connect(ftpserver);
                } catch (SocketException e1)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                try
                {
                    boolean login = ftp.login(ftpusername, ftppassword);
                } catch (IOException e1)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                int reply;
                reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
                if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
                {
                    ftp.disconnect();
                    System.out.println("FTP server refused connection.");
                } else
                {
                    // ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    ftp.enterLocalActiveMode();
                    ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(pdfBean.getFileLocation());
                    /* FTPFile[] */
                    ftpFiles = ftp.listFiles();
                    /* FTPFile[] */// ftpFiles = ftp.listFiles();
                    // ftp.completePendingCommand();
                }

                String fileName = pdfBean.getFileLocation() + "/"
                        + pdfBean.getFileName();
                if ("/interface/oracle/dds/generic/hold/TIF"
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(pdfBean.getFileLocation()))
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    String F = pdfBean.getFileName().replaceAll(".PDF",
                            ".TIF");
                    // FTPFile[] ftpFiles =
                    // ftp.listFiles(pdfBean.getFileLocation());
                    for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles)
                    {
                        if (ftpFile.getName().equals(F))
                        {
                            fileName = pdfBean.getFileLocation()
                                    .concat("/").concat(F);
                            i = 1;
                        }

                    }
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        F = pdfBean.getFileName().replaceAll(".PDF",
                                ".TIFF");
                        for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles)
                        {
                            if (ftpFile.getName().equals(F))
                            {
                                fileName = pdfBean.getFileLocation()
                                        .concat("/").concat(F);
                                i = 1;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    int Repcode = ftp.getReplyCode();
                    //
                    // System.out.println(Repcode);
                    /* if(fileName.endsWith(".TIF")) */

                    InputStream is = (InputStream) ftp.retrieveFileStream(fileName);
                    Repcode = ftp.getReplyCode();
                    System.out.println(Repcode);
                    // ftp.completePendingCommand();
                    Repcode = ftp.getReplyCode();
                    System.out.println(Repcode);
                    ra1 = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(is);
                    tiffPages = TiffImage.getNumberOfPages(ra1);
                    System.out.println("No of pages in image is : "
                            + tiffPages);
                    for (int a = 1; a <= tiffPages; a++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Image img = TiffImage.getTiffImage(ra1, a);
                            if (img != null)
                            {
                                if (img.getScaledWidth() > 500
                                        || img.getScaledHeight() > 700)
                                {
                                    img.scaleToFit(800, 800);
                                }
                                doc.setPageSize(new Rectangle(img
                                        .getScaledWidth(), img
                                        .getScaledHeight()));
                                img.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                                cb.addImage(img);
                                // doc.
                                doc.newPage();
                                // ++pages;
                            }
                        } catch (Throwable e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Exception " + " page "
                                    + (a + 1) + " " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    is.close();
                    ra1.close();

                }
                else{

                    InputStream pdf = ftp.retrieveFileStream(fileName);
                    if(pdf != null) {
                        PdfReader pdfRea = new PdfReader(pdf);
                        readers.add(pdfRea);
                        totalPages += pdfRea.getNumberOfPages();   
                    }


                    /*totalPages += pdfRea.getNumberOfPages();


                    PdfImportedPage page;
                    int currentPageNumber = 0;
                    int pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
                    Iterator<PdfReader> iteratorPDFReader = readers.iterator();

                    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,
                            BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                   // Loop through the PDF files and add to the output.
                   while (iteratorPDFReader.hasNext()) {
                       PdfReader pdfReader = iteratorPDFReader.next();

                       // Create a new page in the target for each source page.
                       while (pageOfCurrentReaderPDF < pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
                           doc.newPage();
                           pageOfCurrentReaderPDF++;
                           currentPageNumber++;
                           page = write.getImportedPage(pdfReader, pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
                           cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

                           // Code for pagination.
                           cb.beginText();
                           cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 9);
                           cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, ""
                                   + currentPageNumber + " of " + totalPages, 520, 5, 0);
                           cb.endText();
                       }
                       pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
                   }*/
                }

                ftp.logout();
                ftp.disconnect();
                ftp = null;
            }}



            PdfImportedPage page;
            int currentPageNumber = 0;
            int pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
            Iterator<PdfReader> iteratorPDFReader = readers.iterator();

            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,
                    BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
           // Loop through the PDF files and add to the output.
           while (iteratorPDFReader.hasNext()) {
               PdfReader pdfReader = iteratorPDFReader.next();

               // Create a new page in the target for each source page.
               while (pageOfCurrentReaderPDF < pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
                   doc.newPage();
                   pageOfCurrentReaderPDF++;
                   currentPageNumber++;
                   page = write.getImportedPage(pdfReader, pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
                   cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

                   // Code for pagination.
                   cb.beginText();
                   cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 9);
                   cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, ""
                           + currentPageNumber + " of " + totalPages, 520, 5, 0);
                   cb.endText();
               }
               pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
           }
        }
        doc.close();
        write.flush();
        write.close();
        System.out.println("done printing");

    }


    FileInputStream fiss = new FileInputStream(temp);  
    bis = new BufferedInputStream(fiss);
    response.reset();
```